# c recv until zero is returned

Tags: c, sockets, recv

In my client code (I control the server code too) I want to do something like this;

```
while( (result = recv(sock_fd, in_buff, SRV_BUFF_SIZE, 0)) >= 0 )
{
    // do something with in_buff    
}
printf("Exited recv loop with result = %i\n", result);
```

But of course `recv` never returns zero unless the server closes the socket.

Is there a way for the server to send something that convinces `recv` to exit?  I don't think that I should have to keep opening and closing the socket (seems wasteful).

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `fcntl()` and `F_SETFL` and `O_NONBLOCK`?  Beware: spinning may be worse than blocking.  And you are right that `recv()` won't return `0` unless the other end of the socket is closed.

Comment: The answer may be to wrap the existing messages in a protocol that allows the receive side to exit the loop when a message is finished.

Comment: You're not telling what protocol you're using. If it's tcp or stream unix sockets, mention it clearly. Notice that with datagram and seqpacket sockets, you can really send and receive 0-size packets, so your claim that "recv never returns zero unless the server closes the socket" is false.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No, that's only true for stream sockets. And with tcp sockets, there's "urgent data", `MSG_OOB`, `POLLPRI`, etc.